# Cannot install scipy (1.9.1) on 32-bit Windows 10 using pip (ERROR: ResolutionImpossible)

Tags: python, numpy, pip, scipy, 32-bit

I've been installing **python 3.10** packages on **32-bit Windows 10**. I had no problems with **numpy** or **pandas** but cannot seem to install **scipy**. I've been researching on the matter and found out **scipy version 1.9.1** seems to have **32-bit** wheels available. Versions > 1.9.2 do not install. Version 1.8.1 seems too old to succeed. This is the closest I got to installing the scipy library. This is also the only installation pip has failed me with so far. I just wanted to ask if there might be a workaround for it.
I'm posting the entire log below.

```
Collecting scipy==1.9.1
  Using cached scipy-1.9.1.tar.gz (42.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [34 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "aarch64" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine == "arm64" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'platform_machine == "loongarch64"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "loongarch64" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and (platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin") and platform_machine != "loongarch64" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.11" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting meson-python>=0.8.1
        Using cached meson_python-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
      Collecting meson==0.62.2
        Using cached meson-0.62.2-py3-none-any.whl (864 kB)
      Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.21
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      Collecting pybind11<2.11.0,>=2.4.3
        Using cached pybind11-2.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (222 kB)
      Collecting pythran<0.12.0,>=0.9.12
        Using cached pythran-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel<0.38.0
        Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.22.3
        Using cached numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-win32.whl (12.2 MB)
      ERROR: Cannot install numpy==1.21.6 and numpy==1.22.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

      The conflict is caused by:
          The user requested numpy==1.22.3
          The user requested numpy==1.21.6

      To fix this you could try to:
      1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
      2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

      ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: I think I may be looking at the origin of this error in the source of the .toml file in release 1.9.x of scipy. There's conflicting lines specifying numpy==1.21.6 with python_version=='3.10' and with platform_system=='Windows' it's numpy==1.22.3 and the same python_version=='3.10'. This matches the output I'm getting while installing. I think it's a bug on their side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately dealing with those kinds of configuration in pyproject.toml is error prone. I think you're correct. However, this will probably be a won't fix as our current build chain is not set up to handle win32 (hence lack of win32 wheels for >= 1.9.2).

You might have luck with 1.9.0 or earlier.

If you can please consider moving to 64 bit wheels, 32 bit wheels have a low probability of appearing in the near future, due to difficulties with the build chain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Accepted. Maybe I'll try clone the repo sometime. It might still install who knows. Trying to help support pip. I lack 64-bit drivers on this machine.